# long range antenna

Tags: wireless, mobile

we want to provide mobiles and laptops in site B with internet connection using long range antenna, but it is not permitted to put any communication devices (ex. AP) there.

1- is there any suggestions?

2- can mobiles and laptops communicate directly with long range antenna (distance ~1 KM)?
[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:  This is not going to work.

Depending where you live, there are regulations that specify the transmitter power and antenna type (gain).  This varies with the frequency band you are using (2.4GHz vs 5 GHz).

Remember that WiFi is two-way communication.  Not only does your AP have to have a strong enough signal for your clients to hear it, but your clients also have to have a strong enough signal for the AP to hear them. Even if you have sufficient power and proper antenna for the access point, your mobile clients will almost certainly not.  Laptops and phones simply do not have enough power and high gain antennas to make this work.

Comment: Great answer @Ron_Trunk, What if he used a repeater? Will the mobile clients be able to hear that ?

Answer (score 3):

While it **can** work using highly directional antennas (which increase both transmission and reception at the AP for devices in the correct spatial region relative to the antenna, compensating for the limited antenna and output of the mobile device while staying in legal limits for EIRP) your "illustration" would appear to show a situation where it's **unlikely to work.**

For success, an essentially radio dead coverage area is best, because the antenna gain of a directional antenna also picks up any noise source or competing wi-fi in the coverage area. So it works fairly well for coverage in a literal open field environment, not at all in an urban environment.

Even in a radio-dead coverage area, putting the end use devices inside a building tends to negatively impact coverage in a big way. They are already hampered by a weak signal and a small antenna - adding another layer of interference and signal loss around them tends to make this unviable. Point to point links exterior to the buildings leading to APs in the buildings is the only reliable method - you might find some spots in the remote building where you get coverage, but you can't begin to expect coverage of a whole building.

I have two APs with sector antennas in normal use serving outside open field areas with reliable operation at ~0.5 Km ranges, and someone I know has a setup with mountain-top sector APs where he's had to turn down to keep them from getting 2+ Km connections - normal use is about 1 Km, but to devices that are not in buildings. These are the exact opposite of urban installs - there is basically nothing there in the WiFi bands except our APs and the end-use devices.